# JS: external loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have lot of pages in different domains that need to include some .js .css and html. I want to "remotely" update the included code.

So in those static pages I tought placing:

```
<script src="http://centraldomain.com/include.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then in that file do:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="results"></div>');

$('#result').load('http://domain.com/include-rest.html');
```

and in that html place all the html I want to insert in those pages, eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
some html without <head> or <body>
```

Is this the best approach to take? Is there any cross domain or XSS attack security issue I'm not taking into account?

Thanks

Comment: when I try to load() into the div I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.com/include.html. Origin http://.com.ar is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: That error is because you're loading a file from a different domain.  Try setting `crossDomain` to `true`

Comment: didn't work on Safari :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing your code loading using external resources, you can instead import a single file an use a resource loader to manage dependancies. Rather than having external scripts execute code (tripping same origin policies), you can manage everything in one place and side-step any cross domain issues.

yepnope.js is an asynchronous resource that would help. You can use test for whatever site your on, import files necessary, then test what site your on to determine if you need to execute any further code.

Take a look at http://yepnopejs.com/ -- here's a quick look.

```
yepnope([{
  test : /* boolean(ish) - Something truthy that you want to test             */,
  yep  : /* array (of strings) | string - The things to load if test is true  */,
  nope : /* array (of strings) | string - The things to load if test is false */,
  both : /* array (of strings) | string - Load everytime (sugar)              */,
  load : /* array (of strings) | string - Load everytime (sugar)              */,
  callback : /* function ( testResult, key ) | object { key : fn }            */,
  complete : /* function                                                      */
}, ... ]);
```

Comment: and how would I include the external html inside the div?

Comment: You wouldn't get the issue, because the JS loaded from centraldomain.com would execute on domain.com, and so when domain.com tried to $.load() code from domain.com, there would be no cross domain issues.

Comment: i tried load()ing the remote html from the console (which would execute on domain.com, not centraldomain.com) and I still got the cross domain alert, even if I set crossDomain: true

Comment: On domain.com you're trying to $.load('remotedomain.com')? You could always try this cross-domain patch: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/